# Json is being put in array into the wrong order

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am working on an android app which is retrieving information from a MySQL database.

The android app is posting to a PHP REST web service and the web service is returning JSON data.

What I am currently trying to do is get a list of databases on the MySQL server in alphabetical order. When the JSON is printed to the logcat it seems to be in the right order but when I call json.names() on the JSONObject in android it then has the databases in the wrong order.

For example, the logcat might shown it as db1, db2, db3, db4 but when the array is returned from json.names() its then appears to be in a random order. For example db4, db1, db3, db2.

Is there a particular reason for this and how can I stop this from happening.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Below is the code that processes the JSON

```
public void processConnectDBResult(IConnectDB iConnectDb, JSONObject json)
    {
        ArrayList<String> databases = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tables = null;
        HashMap<String, List<String>> dbAndTables = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        try
        {
            //Retrieve the array of the databases
            JSONArray databasesJson = json.names();

            for (int i = 0; i < databasesJson.length(); i++)
            {
                databases.add(databasesJson.getString(i));
                //Retrieve the tables array from the database array
                JSONArray tablesJson = json.getJSONArray(databasesJson.getString(i));

                tables = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int j = 0; j < tablesJson.length(); j++)
                {
                    tables.add(tablesJson.getString(j));
                }
                dbAndTables.put(databases.get(i), tables);
            }
            iConnectDb.processDatabaseRetrievalResult("SUCCESS", "", databases, dbAndTables);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post the java code of your JSONObject

Comment: @user2511882 I've posted the code